# Problemas con el git push heroku master

Tags: python, django, heroku

Buenas como están espero que bien,estoy teniendo problemas para realizar un push a un proyecto echo en python utilizando el framework django para heroku que pueden verlo por este link https://github.com/atag102/pruebaGit3.git me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probá actualizando el `pipfile.lock`. Intentá corriendo lo siguiente:

```
pipenv lock
```

Comment: Antes no deberia borrar el pipfile.lock ?

Comment: Gracias, el problema era ese y ademas de que en el pipfile abia escrito :  [requires]
-python_full_version = "3.6.5"